# Unit snap.networkmanager.service could not be found

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm a complete noob concerning networking on Linux, and only a beginner on Linux in general. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 and I want to enable mobile broadband on my laptop. I found this documentation: https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/installation

I installed the network manager, but when I run

```
snap interfaces network-manager
```

I get this result

```
Slot                     Plug
:firewall-control        network-manager
:modem-manager           network-manager
:network                 network-manager
:network-setup-observe   network-manager
:ppp                     network-manager
network-manager:service  -
-                        network-manager:nmcli
-                        network-manager:wpa
```

which doesn't look right. And when I run the next step to check the installation

```
systemctl status snap.networkmanager
```

I get this

```
Unit snap.networkmanager.service could not be found.
```

Ignoring these I tried the stuff in the section for cellular connections

```
sudo modem-manager.mmcli -L
```

which resulted in this

```
error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on and how to correct it?

Comment: Well, one thing I know is that "snap interfaces network-manager" should now be "snap connections network-manager".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer. But I think that you might need to connect the `network-manager:nmcli` plug to the `network-manager:service` slot by:

```
sudo snap connect network-manager:nmcli network-manager:service
```

So that the connections look more like the documentation. See more on connections here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management. Then I think that you need start the snap version of network manager by first getting the service name from:

```
systemctl list-units
```

It should be something like `snap.network-manager.networkmanager`. You can start it by running:

```
sudo service snap.network-manager.networkmanager start
```

I recommend shutting down the apt version of the network-manager first just to be safe:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

You can confirm that the service is running by:

```
sudo service snap.network-manager.networkmanager status
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I completely gave up on this way back when, apparently my chipset is not supported by Ubuntu. But thanks for replying.