# Is NetworkManager managing my network interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have gone through previous answers to this question. They have not helped me as I seem to be getting conflicting signals. Reproducing outputs of various commands below.

<------------ Outputs pasted below ------------->

```
Desktop$ grep -i renderer /etc/netplan/*.yaml

/etc/netplan/00-default-nm-renderer.yaml:  renderer: NetworkManager

/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
    
    Desktop$ service --status-all | grep -i net
```

```
Desktop$ sudo service network-manager status

Unit network-manager.service could not be found.
```

```
    Desktop$ sudo service systemd-networkd status
    
    ● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
    
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    
         Active: inactive (dead)
    
           Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
```

```
Desktop$ ps aux | grep network-manager

root         831  0.0  0.0 393544 15900 ?        Ssl  11:02   0:01 /snap/network-manager/653/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --config-dir=/var/snap/network-manager/653/conf.d/ --config=/snap/network-manager/653/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf --log-level=INFO --no-daemon

xxxxx+    4521  0.0  0.0  17676  2636 pts/0    S+   11:57   0:00 grep --color=auto network-manager
```

```
   Desktop$ dpkg --get-selections | grep network-manager
```

```
Desktop$ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service

Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found.
```

```
    Desktop$ systemctl list-units | grep -i net
    
      sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:01:00.0-net-enp1s0.device                       loaded active     plugged   I211 Gigabit Network Connection
    
      sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.4-0000:02:00.0-net-enp2s0.device                       loaded active     plugged   I211 Gigabit Network Connection
    
      sys-devices-virtual-net-docker0.device                                                   loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0
    
      sys-subsystem-net-devices-docker0.device                                                 loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/net/devices/docker0
    
      sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp1s0.device                                                  loaded active     plugged   I211 Gigabit Network Connection
    
      sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp2s0.device                                                  loaded active     plugged   I211 Gigabit Network Connection
    
      run-snapd-ns-network\x2dmanager.mnt.mount                                                loaded active     mounted   /run/snapd/ns/network-manager.mnt
    
      snap-network\x2dmanager-653.mount                                                        loaded active     mounted   Mount unit for network-manager, revision 653
    
      networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              loaded active     running   Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
    
      snap.network-manager.networkmanager.service                                              loaded active     running   Service for snap application network-manager.networkmanager
    
      systemd-resolved.service                                                                 loaded active     running   Network Name Resolution 
        
      systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                loaded active     running   Network Time Synchronization
    
      network-online.target                                                                    loaded active     active    Network is Online  
             
      network.target                                                                           loaded active     active    Network       
                  
      nss-lookup.target                                                                        loaded active     active    Host and Network Name Lookups
```

<-----------------END OF OUTPUT-------------------------->

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: It looks like you have the snap version of network-manager installed. Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202157/167115) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit snap.networkmanager.service could not be found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142029/unit-snap-networkmanager-service-could-not-be-found)

Comment: First problem... you have multiple .yaml files in /etc/netplan. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a Desktop or Server installation? What version Ubuntu? Next, tell us your problem, or why you ask about NetworkManager, and maybe we can come up with a more complete answer.

Comment: Mchid,

I am running ubuntu 20.04.

I will follow these instructions but I am trying to understand what the current state of my system is and whether or not NetworkManager is 
managing my network and network interfaces.

Heynnema,

~/Desktop$ cat /etc/netplan/00-default-nm-renderer.yaml

network:

  renderer: NetworkManager

:~/Desktop$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system

network:

  version: 2

  renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: @Ajit Yes. If so, I believe this should show that `snap.network-manager.networkmanager.service ` is running.

Comment: Please try: `sudo service NetworkManager status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 
Desktop$ sudo service NetworkManager status

Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.

Comment: How about: `ps aux | grep NetworkManager`

Comment: root         831  0.0  0.0 393856 16200 ?        Ssl  Dec30   0:03 /snap/network-manager/653/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --config-dir=/var/snap/network-manager/653/conf.d/ --config=/snap/network-manager/653/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf --log-level=INFO --no-daemon